# get confused of the "final" usage, and the printed names printed out why was like that

Tags: java

why the final names printed were the same, if `this.name = name` is instead, the name would be changed.

another question is in class Name `public name(){}` was created for? whether just use the next line is ok.

```
class Name
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Name() {}

    public Name(String firstName, String lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return this.lastName;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    private final Name name;

    public Person(Name name)
    {
        this.name = new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getLastName());
    }

    public Name getName()
    {
        return new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getLastName());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Name n =new Name("wukong", "sun");
        Person p= new Person(n);
        System.out.println(p.getName().getFirstName() + p.getName().getLastName());
        n.setFirstName("bajie");
        System.out.println(p.getName().getFirstName() + p.getName().getLastName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider proper intending code and ask question with numbers.

Comment: Don't ask questions with numbers, just ask clear questions. This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you are mixing up all objects and references over here. First of all please change your getName() function to :-

```
public Name getName()
       {
           return this.name;
       }
```

This will return the current name object associated with the person class and not create a new instance of name like you are doin when you return new Name(...).

And second thing changing values of n (name object ) will not affect the person object p that contains a different instance of name object.

for changing firstName value of your p object replace this

```
n.setFirstName("bajie");
```

with this:-

```
p.getName().setFirstName("bajie");
```

Edit:- I just saw that your Name field is set as final hence it can be only instantiated and assigned value once in the constructor, after that it cannot change (the reference) although you can reassign p.getName().getFirstName() (Since the object is changing and not the reference).

And for the second question it is a default constructor i.e a no-argument constructor automatically generated unless you define another constructor (Which in your case you have defined)

Answer (score 0):

### Note about `final`

```
private final Name name;
```

The `final` modifier indicates that the **reference** to the `Name` object pointed by the field `name` cannot be changed once it is assigned in a constructor or init block. This does **not** mean that the **object** pointed by this reference cannot be changed.

*Note: Between your field declaration and its first initialization, it is in a "blank" state, waiting for init.*

> if "this.name = name" is instead, the name would be changed

#### Comparison

```
this.name = new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getLastName());
```

This piece of code creates a **new `Name` object** and initialize your field with a reference to that new object. The created object is initialized with the same content as the argument `name`. If you later call `setFirstName("bajie");` on the name you passed as argument here, it won't change the field's content (because it's another object).

```
this.name = name;
```

This piece of code assigns the parameter `name`'s reference to the `this.name` field. If you later call `setFirstName("bajie");` on the name you passed as argument here, it **will** change the field's content, because it is **the same object**. It won't change the reference held by the field though.

### About the no-arg constructor

> another question is in class Name "public name(){}" was created for?

The empty no-arg constructor is the "default" constructor.

However, if you declare another constructor (which is the case here with the second constructor `public Name(String firstName, String lastName)`), then the default constructor does not exist anymore.
If you want to be able to instantiate a `Name` without args, you need to redeclare the no-arg constructor.

Answer (score 0):

**why the final names printed were the same**

you will find answer in `Person` constructor, `this.name = new Name(name.getFirstName(), name.getLastName());` you are not assigning name to person, but you create new objects with it fields. Hence this statement `n.setFirstName("bajie");` is not affecting your `p`

**if "this.name = name" is instead, the name would be changed.**

try it

**is in class Name "public name(){}" was created for? wether just use the next line is ok.**
some of frameworks require class to have no-arg construcor. as you defined own constructor you are loosing default no-arg constructor. this line creates one for you